# Compute a derivative using the definition and find a functional equation?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have this function:
$f(x) = f(x+y) - f(y) -x^2y - xy^2$

and i have to assume that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}= 1$

and i already know that its derivative (using the formal definition) is:
$f'(x) = f'(x+y) -2xy -y^2$

My question is how can i get $f'(x)$ in terms of x?

Wolfram alpha said that is something called functional equation which is $f'(x) = 1+x^2$, but i do not know what is that.

I would appreciate is somebody can help me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your equation as
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+x^2y+xy^2+f(y)
$$
so
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x)+x^2y+xy^2+f(y)-f(x)}{y}=
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{x^2y+xy^2+f(y)}{y}
$$
I bet you can take on from here.

Comment: @egarro Now you can also determine $f$ and show it indeed satisfies the original equation.

Comment: How can i do that? If a do an integration i will get: $f(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + C$ thats what you mean?

Comment: @egarro You find a constant of integration, but you can know its value by substituting $x=y=0$ in the original equation and find $f(0)$, so this determines $C$.

Comment: So C = 0? right?

Comment: @egarro Yes. Then verifying the equation is just an easy computation.

Comment: Thanks for your advises! This community is great, i learned a lot of math. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all notice that (insert $-x$ instead of $y$)

$$
f' (x) = f' (0) + x^2
$$

On the other hand, we know that

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x = f'(0) =1 
$$

so

$$
f'(x) = 1+x^2
$$

Comment: This assumes the derivative exists. How can you be sure of it?

Comment: @egreg at 0? we are given that the limit exists and equals 1.

Comment: And so? When you write $f'(x)=f'(0)+x^2$ you're *assuming* the derivative exists at $x$, without having proved it does. The "formal derivative” computed by the OP suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @egreg OK, I should have wrote that any solution is obviously differentiable at any point (divide both sides by x and apply $\lim_{x \to 0}$ to both sides and LHS exists). It's an interesting question, without 2nd condition, to give a solution without any points of differentiability